# Filter Column based on Actual Cell Address

Tags: vba, excel, filter

**I have search a tons of sites but nothing found. Please help.**

I'm new to VBA and there is something I cannot just record in Macro Recorder.

**Here's my problem:**

I have a sheet **Reference**, filtered column A contains the **actual cell address** (ex. A5 contains F1, A6 contains F2, etc) for another sheet called Target.

**I need:**

1. I need a **button** to filter Target sheet based on column A in Reference sheet.
2. I need those filtered cells in Target sheet to be highlighted.

**Note:**

> Only F column in Target sheet needs to be filtered.
>
> Column B in Reference sheet is filtered, meaning, column A was filtered too.

[Check this image to see what I'm trying to imply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgDM5.png)

This is the code to filter B. I just need the corresponding value of those filtered cell to column A (which are the actual address of cells in Target column)

```
Sub RefreshFilter()
'
' a Macro

    'Unfilter if data in sheet is filtered.
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    'Refresh Data
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

   'Filter Row B with RED fill
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB( _
        255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
End Sub
```

[Here's the actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guFDX.png)

Comment: May i know, what you want to do after the filter in Target

Comment: Going to highlight those cells that were filtered.

Comment: Is this possible @Karthick? :(

Comment: I would say, All are possible

Comment: I don't see why this should not be possible, but it would help if you refine your question. You are likely to receive quicker, better help.

Comment: Please help me. :(

Comment: Hope I made it simpler @MarioTacke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub RefreshFilter()
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim filterRange As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim RngOne As Range, cell2 As Range
    Dim LastCell As Long
    Dim arrList() As String
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Dim RngOne2 As Range, cell3 As Range
    Dim LastCell2 As Long
    Dim arrList2() As String
    Dim lngCnt2 As Long

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reference")
    Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cells")

    'Unfilter if data in sheet is filtered.
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    'Refresh Data
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

   'Filter Row B with RED fill
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB( _
        255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor


    'I created an array to put the filtered cells in column A of reference sheet
    'And paste those values to another sheeet named Cells
    LastRow = src.Range("B" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set filterRange = src.Range("B" & LastRow)
    Set copyRange = src.Range("A123:A" & LastRow)
    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A1")

    With Sheets("Reference")
    LastCell = .Range("A" & Sheets("Reference").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngOne = .Range("A1:A" & LastCell)
    End With

    'load values into an array
    lngCnt = 0
    For Each cell2 In RngOne
    ReDim Preserve arrList(lngCnt)
    arrList(lngCnt) = cell2.Text
    lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
    Next

    'I loaded again the values of cells sheet to arraylist2
    'this is just like the structure of array above, I did loops
    With Sheets("Cells")
    LastCell2 = .Range("A" & Sheets("Cells").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngOne2 = .Range("A1:A" & LastCell2)
    End With

    'load values into an array
    lngCnt2 = 0
    For Each cell3 In RngOne2
    ReDim Preserve arrList2(lngCnt2)
    arrList2(lngCnt2) = cell3.Text

    'I just did some recordings in macro to get this
    Application.Goto Sheets("Raw Data").Range(cell3.Text)
        With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    lngCnt2 = lngCnt2 + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Karthick Check this out. :D

Comment: Added my solution just by any chance someone will encounter the same problem as mine. :D Happy codings!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code alone after your B column filter.

```
Sub changecolor_Final()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim r As Range
    lastfilterrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range("A5:A" & lastfilterrow)
    For Each cl In r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        With Worksheets("Target")
            .Range(cl).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: No no. :( Hmmmn. But thanks for trying. The F1 in Column A is actually the actual address of target sheet. So meaning, the cell F1 in target sheet must be filtered so as F2. There are no duplicates in Column A.

Comment: Please check the image I attached. It'll be more easier to explain to that. Please please.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GAc9s.png

Comment: It's not the value that I'm looking after. It's the actual address cell in the Target sheet.

Comment: Hi @Karthick. :( I need to filter the those in Target sheet. Plus it's not the font color that supposedly changed. It's the fill color. :(

Comment: Plus it needs to be a button. :(

Comment: @MielYan please check the edited

Comment: Hi @Kathrick. It's not working. Doesn't do anything

Comment: why its not. can you please explain

Comment: I don't know why it is not working. Can you screen shot what the code supposedly doing?

Comment: Please check the image i have attached

Comment: As this is my understanding with your question

1) Filter the Content in B Column based on your text
2) Take the corresponding A column Content (ie Cell Range) 
3) Locate the Cell address in Target Sheet and take that Value
4) Search that value for entire Column F in Target Sheet. if it present, Apply the Color. Please check the image attached

Comment: No @Kathrick. The expected values that are highlighted in F column of Target Sheet should NOT because of the value itself. It's the CELL itself. F1, F2, F3, F4, F5 are addresses of CELLS in Target sheet.

Comment: Check this from your screenshot.http://i.stack.imgur.com/FgDM5.png

Comment: Everything that you have said is correct apart from number 4. I'm not looking for the value of the cell. I'm finding the cell itself (ex. find the cell C4, regardless of its value)

Comment: as per your requirements F1, F2, F3 & F5 should be highlighted. Am i right?

Comment: @MielYan edited pls check

Comment: It still does nothing. :( I think you are trying to find the red in B column. Is there any chance to not do something in B column cos it has sensitive number on it. I just need the Column A to treat as an array since B was already filtered. This is sheet Reference.

Comment: This is the code that I used to filter the B column of Reference sheet

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB( _
        255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor



>>>>>>>Is there any chance to put that into check_changecolor_function()?

Comment: use cells.autofilter to remove those filters and run the above code. that means add cells.autofilter at the beginning of my code

Comment: Go an error. Unable to get the autofilter property of the range class. :(

    Call Changecolor(Cells.AutoFilter, Range("B35:825"))

Comment: @MielYan add Cells.Autofilter before Call Changecolor("Red", Range("B5:B9"))

Comment: I cannot remove the filter made in column B because that's the reason why I'm getting the cell address in column A.

Comment: can you please show your full code? so that i can understand whats your problem

Comment: I'm getting what you are trying to say. But the screen shot is just an example of what I'm trying to do. What I did to column B is this code

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB( _
        255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

>>>So basically, I need to put that to the function we are trying to call.

Comment: This is the the code.

Sub RefreshFilter()
'
' a Macro
    
    'Unfilter if data in sheet is filtered.
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    'Refresh Data
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
   'Filter Row B with RED fill
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB( _
        255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
End Sub

Comment: I updated the question and add the actual screenshot

Comment: Updated the Actual Screenshot

Comment: @MielYan use the edited code after the line `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor`

Comment: Has an error in .Range(cl).Interior.ColorIndex = 6. Application-defined or object-defined

Comment: The lastfilterrow contains the how many rows are they in target sheet; CL in .Range(cl) contains the value of column A in target sheet @Karthick

Comment: Hi @Kathrick! :) Got the answer along the way! Thank youuuu so much for your time

Comment: kindly mark it as this is solution for your question.